# Change commit message after push+merge when source branch was deleted

Tags: git

I locally created a new branch `test` and make some changes. Then I did commit and pushed changes to remote repo. Then I merged branch `test` to branch `develop` with option `Delete source branch after merge`. In remote repo I only have branch `develop`. Locally I've two branches.

Now how can I change a commit message in remote repo? I'm confused, that I'dont have this branch in remote repo.

Comment: Repos are independent from each other... they can hold different branches each.

Answer (score 1):

A branch is a pointer to a specific commit.  Commits don't exist only on a branch.  To update the commit message, you will need to do a `git rebase -i <commit sha before the one you want>` this will open an editor with all the commits listed with the word `pick`.  For the commit that you want to change the wording change `pick` to `reword` and you will be able to update the message.

You don't see the branch on the remote repo, because in your MR you said to delete the source branch.  So it removed that branch from the remote, however if you didn't delete it locally it will still be present.

WARNING!
This is changing the history of the branch and the commit will be a new SHA which may/will cause problems with other branches.  If you are not the only person using the repository or are new to git, I don't recommend this.  Instead just leave the message as it.